# Change parent AND child div on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, divider

Some code...

```
<a href="#">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="image.jpg">
<div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
</a>
```

and some css to start...

```
.col-md-4 {
background color: #000;
}
.text {
color: #fff;
}
```

I want to change the col-md-4 IMAGE opacity on rollover. At the same time, i also need the TEXT to change color on rollover.

I can get one or the other working - text or div, but not both.

Any idea what I need to do to target both on rollover?

Comment: Move the hover to the anchor rather than the div. You be aware that changing the divs opacity will **also** change the opacity of the text.

Comment: any way to target both independently?
For example - when rollover of PARENT div - change image opacity to .6 and change text color but RETAIN full opacity for the text?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net Btw it sounds like you want to change the image's opacity, not the parent. If you change the parent div (col-md-4) you will be affecting the opacity of the child elements. You should look at getting the hover for the image and then getting its immediate sibling with the ~ selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: To change one on the other element's hover, you'll need to use jquery as you can only change the immediate next sibling's properties, not the previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I believe that this is what you are after.

```
   .col-md-4:hover img {
    opacity:0.6
    }
```

This will change the opacity of the image **only** when the div is hovered.

For the text change

```
   .col-md-4:hover .text {
    color: /* other color */
    }
```

Comment: that works for the image - but how can i get it to also change the text color inside as a child div?